# INTERSECT OPERATOR in set analysis qlikview

Tags: qlikview

QLIKVIEW DEVELOPERS:

I am creating a set analysis.

```
sum({<Market={"APAC"},[SUB-CATEGORY]={"arts"}>}sales)
sum({<Market={"APAC"},[SUB-CATEGORY]*={"arts"}>}sales)
```

What is the role of `*` in the second expression? both the expressions are resulting the same output.

Answer (score 1):

The normal behaviour of set analysis is to force the field to the value or set of values used in the set analysis expression.

On the first expression, no matter what you have selected in the document, the SUB-CATEGORY field will always be "arts".

On the second expression, the selections you made on the SUB-CATEGORY field will have an impact on the expression :

- If nothings is selected (meaning that all field values are considered), the intersection between all and "arts" will result in "arts" being selected and the sum will be made assuming that selection.
- If the SUB-CATEGORY field is selected with others value than "arts", the intersection will be an empty set and the Sum will be zero.
- If the SUB-CATEGORY field is selected with "arts" and something else, the intersection will again be as if "arts" is selected.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The ***=** denotes that both user selections and the rules in set analysis are taken into account.

With the **=** symbol the user's selections are completely ignored.